# Django debug error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following in my model:

```
 class info(models.Model):
     add = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

An in the views when i say
              info_l = info.objects.filter(id=1)
              logging.debug(info_l.name)

i get an error saying name doesnt exist at debug statement.
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'
1.How can this be resolved.
2.Also how to query for only one field instead of selecting all like select name from info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.  Selecting Single Items**

It looks like you're trying to get a single object.  Using `filter` will return a `QuerySet` object (as is happening in your code), which behaves more like a list (and, as you've noticed, lacks the `name` attribute).

You have two options here.  First, you can just grab the first element:

```
info_l = info.objects.filter(id=1)[0]
```

You could also use the `objects.get` method instead, which will return a single object (and raise an exception if it doesn't exist):

```
info_l = info.objects.get(id=1)
```

Django has some pretty good documentation on QuerySets, and it may be worth taking a look at it:
[Docs on using filters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)
[`QuerySet` reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)

**2.  Retrieving Specific Fields**

Django provides the [`defer`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer-fields) and [`only`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only-fields) methods, which will let you choose specific fields from the database, rather than fetching everything at once.  These don't actually prevent the fields from being read; rather, it loads them lazily.  `defer` is an "opt-in" mode, which lets you specify what fields should be lazily loaded.  `only` is "out-out" -- you call it, and only the fields you pass will by eagerly loaded.

So in your example, you'd want to do something like this:

```
info_l = info.objects.filter(id=1).only('name')[0]
```

Though with a model as simple as the example you give, I wouldn't worry much at all about limiting fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.What i meant to say is for ex:
select name from info; instead of doing a select * from info;

Thanks for the reply

Comment: +1 for thoughtful, complete answer pointing to the docs. We need more answers like these. :-)